# Set Instanced Triangles to certain positions on mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

It should look like on picture bellow
[image]Is there a way to set instanced triangles to fill mesh by putting them in positions as shown on image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, to me it is not clear, how it should look like. Could you please provide an image with and another one without triangles in their target position?

Comment: Yes, I've published image to make things more clear.